# stat lib/ld-2.8.so No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, arm, embedded-linux

I am new to embedded linux.

I need to integrate TI's Digital Video Software Development Kit ([DVSDK](http://software-dl.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/dvsdk/DVSDK_4_00/4_02_00_06/exports/dvsdk_dm368-evm_4_02_00_06_setuplinux)) with libMirlin_arm_2010_q1_202.so.

I can build the TI DVSDK using the codesourcery arm-2009q1-203 toolchain and the [RidgeRun](http://www.ridgerun.com/) SDK but libMirlin_arm_2010_q1_202.so was build using the codesourcery arm-2010q1-202 toolchain and I can't get the source code.

Using the arm-2009q1-203 toolchain causes

> libMirlin.so: undefined reference to
>   `std::ctype::_M_widen_init() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.11

which is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4035445/398460) but using the arm-2010q1-202 toolchain causes this

> install: cannot stat
>   `/opt/codesourcery/arm-2010q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib/ld-2.8.so':
>   No such file or directory.

It seems the arm-2010q1-202 toolchain has updated to ld-2.11.1.so.

How can I modify the build configuration to use ld-2.11.1.so rather than ld-2.8.so?

Comment: @0A0D: $PATH => `/opt/codesourcery/arm-2010q1/bin:/home/jacknad/work/sdk/bsp/local/bin:/home/jacknad/work/sdk/bsp/local/sbin:/home/jacknad/work/sdk/bsp/tools:/home/jacknad/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Comment: Your second problem is because the file does not exist. As far as using the newer library, you need to see what the Makefile contains.

Comment: @0A0D: That was it. Just a matter of finding the correct Makefile. Needed to change 8.so to 11.1.so in about a dozen or so places and also bump libstdc++.so from 6.0.10 to 6.0.12. If you move your comment to an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks a million! Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in your path? The makefile?

Your second problem is because the file does not exist. As far as using the newer library, you need to see what the Makefile contains. You need to change 8.so to 11.1.so in probably several places and probably migrate libstdc++.so to 6.0.1.0 to 6.0.1.2.