# Hadoop Pipes Linker error

Tags: c++, hadoop, pipe

when I MAKE word_count, the error is below, what's wrong?

g++ -m64 -I/home/platform/hadoop/include wordcount.cpp -Wall -L/home/platform/hadoop/lib/native -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl -g -O2 -o wordcount
/home/vipshop/platform/hadoop/lib/native/libhadooppipes.a(HadoopPipes.cc.o): In function `HadoopPipes::BinaryProtocol::getPassword(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
(.text._ZN11HadoopPipes14BinaryProtocol11getPasswordERSs[HadoopPipes::BinaryProtocol::getPassword(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)]+0x258): undefined reference to`std::basic_ostream >& std::__ostream_insert >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*, long)'
/home/vipshop/platform/hadoop/lib/native/libhadooppipes.a(HadoopPipes.cc.o): In function `HadoopPipes::BinaryProtocol::getPassword(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
(.text._ZN11HadoopPipes14BinaryProtocol11getPasswordERSs[HadoopPipes::BinaryProtocol::getPassword(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)]+0x2a4): undefined reference to`std::ctype::_M_widen_init() const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [wordcount] Error 1

Comment: [Looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4035723/698839) you are using a different version of g++ than what the hadoop library was compiled with.

What versions of g++ and Hadoop are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)，hadoop version is hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2

Comment: Looks like your best bet is to compile with a newer version of g++.  I think gcc 4.4.7 has worked for me for the CDH5 version of libhadooppipes.